# How do I download a specific revision of llvm?

Tags: svn, clang, llvm

I am trying to patch `clang` with the latest version of [`templight`](http://plc.inf.elte.hu/templight/) (2014 Jan 22). However, this version unfortunately fails to patch `clang 3.4` or `3.5`, and presumably only works with the revision it was designed for (trunk 199501).

How can I obtain this particular revision of clang?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain it via subversion:

```
$ svn checkout https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk@199501
```

it is dated Jan 17, 2014.